# Cross-compiling I2C application

Tags: cross-compiling, i2c

I am try to cross compile a I2C application with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.
and I am facing below issue

auth_app.c:71: undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data'
auth_app.c:77: undefined reference to`i2c_smbus_write_byte_data'
auth_app.c:83: undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data'

but same application I am able to compile successfuly on Host x86 Pc with 
command
gcc auth_app.c -li2c

Can anyone help me what i am missing on cross compilation.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Isharat

Comment: It seems there's an undefined reference to i2c_smbus_read_byte_data. Looks like you're missing libraries or headers for i2c. Can't say much more, because you've not included much info.

Comment: auth_app.c:(.text+0x654): undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte_data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You need to have libi2c compiled for your target platform (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc). For this part it depends on your cross-compilation environment: yocto, buildroot, crosstool-ng ...

Comment: Thanks done this